# Filter firebase parents based on value from the "child" table - Angularfire

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I have these two models structured like this:

```
export interface Establishment {
  id: string;
  establishmentName: string;
  establishmentEmail: string;
  imageUrl: string[];
  price: number;
  maxGuests: number;
  rating: number;
  location: firebase.firestore.GeoPoint;
  description: string;
  selfCatering: boolean;
  createdAt: firebase.firestore.Timestamp;
  updatedAt: firebase.firestore.Timestamp;
}
```

and:

```
export interface Enquiry {
  id: string;
  establishmentId: string;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  bookingStart: firebase.firestore.Timestamp;
  bookingEnd: firebase.firestore.Timestamp;
  createdAt: firebase.firestore.Timestamp;
  updatedAt: firebase.firestore.Timestamp;
}
```

The `establishmentId` is a refference to the document ID as a "foreign key". I want to filter the establishments based on the booking data in the enquiry. Obviously this would be fairly straightforward if I just fetched both collections and filtered it with regular TS. But I was just wondering if there was a much more elegant way using the built in firebase queries. Pseudo-code: `db.collection('establishments').where('enquiries.bookingEnd' '>' 'someDate');`

I've modeled them this way because I want to be able to get them separately as well. Optionally I could duplicate some data into a subcollection and use the new `collectionGroup()` to filter with. Something like this maybe, but again that results in some duplication:

```
export interface Establishment {
  id: string;
  establishmentName: string;
  establishmentEmail: string;
  imageUrl: string[];
  price: number;
  maxGuests: number;
  rating: number;
  location: firebase.firestore.GeoPoint;
  description: string;
  selfCatering: boolean;
  createdAt: firebase.firestore.Timestamp;
  updatedAt: firebase.firestore.Timestamp;
  booking?: {
    enquiryId: string;
    bookingStart: firebase.firestore.Timestamp;
    bookingEnd: firebase.firestore.Timestamp;
  }[];
}
```

So my question is then: what is the best/simplest way to filter establishments based on the booking data, knowing there will be a separate table for the enquiries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore does not allow for queries that span multiple collections of different names.  A single query can only consider data from a single collection at a time.  There are no SQL-like joins and no true foreign keys.  So, what you're trying to do is not possible with a single query.  You definitely have to duplicate data as you propose in order to get this to work.  Duplication of data is common for nosql type databases - it's called "denormalization", and it allows Firestore to scale massively.

Comment: Alright, gotcha. I think what I was most unsure of was whether or not duplication in nosql was a no no, but ofc also if it was possible to do those kinds of queries. I guess there are some trade-offs to be made using firestore. Thanks.